# Collect id in to array

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have array with object in mongoDB. In array sales I have object with id array products and totalPrice I need that my node.js server return array with ids in sales.

```
     {
        "_id": "5d5d066d3d20a50424211e59",
        "sales": [
            {
                "products": [
                    {
                        "_id": "5d5d066d3d20a50424211e5d",
                        "name": "dsdad",
                        "count": 2,
                        "price": 33.5
                    }
                ],
                "_id": "5d5d066d3d20a50424211e5c",
                "totalPrice": 327.4
            },
            {
                "products": [
                    {
                        "_id": "5d5d066d3d20a50424211e5b",
                        "name": "asda",
                        "count": 3,
                        "price": 324
                    }
                ],
                "_id": "5d5d066d3d20a50424211e5a",
                "totalPrice": 22.4
            }
        ],
        "date": 1566400515,
        "status": true
    }
...
]
```

In array `sales` I have object  with `id` array `products` and `totalPrice`
I need that my node.js server return array with ids in sales.

UPDATE. Each object in `sales` have ID. I need array with this ids. Like this:

````
{ "_id": "5d5d066d3d20a50424211e5c"},
{"_id": "5d5d066d3d20a50424211e5a"}
]```
````

Comment: `sales = sales.map(s => s["_id"])`

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: Also, for the post writer- can u give example of expected output? like I said, `sales` is an array so we can't put a `_id` property in there.... you want them as just plain strings inside the sales array?

Comment: @cooperJCW is below the desired output you need?
[
  {
    "_id": "5d5d066d3d20a50424211e59",
    "sales": [
      "5d5d066d3d20a50424211e5c",
      "5d5d066d3d20a50424211e5a"
    ],
     "date": 1566400515,
        "status": true
  }
...
]

Comment: @Gibor This is valid JavaScript code, what are you talking about ... of course you can reference object properties with `obj[propertyname]` - that is nothing new. And I personally think that the author wants an array of all sales ids in his sales array, so this is exactly what he want.

Comment: Pay attention to the `map()` function which transforms **every element in the array** and not the array itself. @Gibor

Comment: paste your schema and query also, you should be able to get the expected data from query itself. as when you are fetching the products you can use `Products.find({},{'_id':1})`

Comment: @MauriceNino oh dam, you're right... I read it completely wrong for some reason lol. Thanks for correction. so it would give am an array of only the "_id" property, if thats what he wants you're perfectly good.

Comment: No problem! Happens to everyone sometimes :) I guess that's what he wants - at least the question sounded like that. @Gibor

Comment: `db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$addFields": {
      "sales": {
        "$map": {
          "input": "$sales",
          "in": { "_id": "$$this._id" }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])`

Answer (score 0):

Just use `map()` to transform your data like so:

```js
let data = 
[
  {
    "_id": "5d5d066d3d20a50424211e59",
    "sales": [
      {
        "products": [
          {
            "_id": "5d5d066d3d20a50424211e5d",
            "name": "dsdad",
            "count": 2,
            "price": 33.5
          }
        ],
        "_id": "5d5d066d3d20a50424211e5c",
        "totalPrice": 327.4
      },
      {
        "products": [
          {
            "_id": "5d5d066d3d20a50424211e5b",
            "name": "asda",
            "count": 3,
            "price": 324
          }
        ],
        "_id": "5d5d066d3d20a50424211e5a",
        "totalPrice": 22.4
      }
    ],
    "date": 1566400515,
    "status": true
  }
];

// Loop over all your items in your data array
data.forEach(d => {
  // Transform each array of sales to an array of ids of sales
  d.sales = d.sales.map(s => s["_id"]);
});

console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const result = [
  {
    _id: '5d5d066d3d20a50424211e59',
    sales: [
      {
        products: [
          {
            _id: '5d5d066d3d20a50424211e5d',
            name: 'dsdad',
            count: 2,
            price: 33.5,
          },
        ],
        _id: '5d5d066d3d20a50424211e5c',
        totalPrice: 327.4,
      },
      {
        products: [
          {
            _id: '5d5d066d3d20a50424211e5b',
            name: 'asda',
            count: 3,
            price: 324,
          },
        ],
        _id: '5d5d066d3d20a50424211e5a',
        totalPrice: 22.4,
      },
    ],
    date: 1566400515,
    status: true,
  },
];

result.forEach((r) => {
  const reference = r;
  if (reference.sales && Array.isArray(reference.sales)) {
    reference.sales = reference.sales.map((m) => { return m._id; });
  }
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Why `const reference = r` this? What are the benefits of it? Also what is the reason for checking if the element is an array?

Comment: When you configure `ESLint` in your code, It doesn't allow to make a change in that variable (`r`), If you try that it gives warning `no-parm-reassign`, That's why I took a new variable (`reference `)  and perform changes into it, Indirectly it make changes in `r` because we directly assign it `const reference = r;` ;

Answer (score 0):

Instead of running map after waiting for documents to be fetched from query why not use the aggregate pipeline to do so as:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      date: 1,
      status: 1,
      sales: {
        $map: {
          input: "$sales",
          as: "item",
          in: "$$item._id"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: sales and products have _id's means they are coming from different collections.

Comment: are you sure? what if the product is an embedded array of objects?

Comment: I am not sure but the embedded objects includes mongo-Id so mentioned

Comment: Even if you create an embedded array of object ,in object while saving mongo always generate _id for indexing if not set _id:false

Answer (score -1):

You can use or import lodash and use the code below it will return the ids of sales.

```
let _ = require('lodash');
let data = [
{
_id: '5d5d066d3d20a50424211e59',
sales: [
  {
    products: [
      {
        _id: '5d5d066d3d20a50424211e5d',
        name: 'dsdad',
        count: 2,
        price: 33.5,
      },
    ],
    _id: '5d5d066d3d20a50424211e5c',
    totalPrice: 327.4,
  },
  {
    products: [
      {
        _id: '5d5d066d3d20a50424211e5b',
        name: 'asda',
        count: 3,
        price: 324,
      },
    ],
    _id: '5d5d066d3d20a50424211e5a',
    totalPrice: 22.4,
  },
  ],
   date: 1566400515,
    status: true
  },
 ];


let ids = _.map(data,(d)=>{
 return _.map(d.sales, (saleItem) => {return saleItem._id;});
})
```

Comment: I know about map. But for me better if response will be only with ids

Comment: So you want ids from Database query only? 
Because this will manipulate the result and return with array of ids only.